# Refrence of hadith of epidemic handshake?

Tags: hadith, fiqh, hadith-interpretation, uloom-al-hadith, greetings

I already tried to Google but couldn't find out
What is the refrence of hadith which prohibits hand shaking with patients of epidemic disease?

Comment: A hadith exists about not shaking hands with a leper, which can be generalized to contagious diseases,

Comment: The hadith @UmH is referring to is quoted in my answer on https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/58369/13438